# In PyCharm (and other JetBrains IDEs), how to configure the background color of tooltip

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

Here's what the popup looks like:

[image]

I want to change the background color to be lighter, but not sure what config I should modify. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at background color style for styles in this section:

1. Settings/Preferences
2. Editor | Color Scheme | General
3. Popups and Hints

**NOTE:** If it's not configurable here, then it takes colors from the GUI Theme (which is not user configurable; you would need to make your own UI theme for that. There are [plenty of them available](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/search?products=pycharm&search=theme) as they are installed as ordinary plugins).

Screenshots are from PhpStorm 2020.2, but it should be the same or very similar in PyCharm as they all build on IntelliJ IDEA platform.

For example, for Quick Documentation (<kbd>Ctrl+Q</kbd> on Windows):

[image]

[image]

Just popup that is shown when you hover over some element/warning (includes docs section as well at the bottom):

[image]

[image]